# error: Load key "path to key": invalid format. When running git commit

Tags: git, ssh-keys

Ive been trying to set up commit signing on github and have followed the guide but I am running into problems.

What I have done so far

*in git bash* `$ ssh-keygen -m PEM -t ed25519 -C "insert email"`

Then I uploaded the key to github

*in git bash* `$ git config --global gpg.format ssh` `$ git config --global user.signingkey 'insert key'`

When I click commit in VSCode it fails with this as command output

```
git -c user.useConfigOnly=true commit --quiet --allow-empty-message --file - -S
error: Load key "C:\\Users\\CoolUser\\AppData\\Local\\Temp/.git_signing_key_tmpnwUfAT": invalid format?

fatal: failed to write commit object
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5bgit%5d%20gpg.format

Comment: `user.signingKey` is either a path to the public key file or the very public key with `key::` prefix. To fix: `git config --global user.signingKey 'key::insert key'` . See also [`git help config`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-config#Documentation/git-config.txt-usersigningKey). The private key needs to be available via `ssh-agent`.